# How to remove special characters without removing text in another language?

Tags: java, regex

I am using the code below to remove smiley and special characters from a string

```
String utf8TweetText  = tweet.getText();
Pattern unicodeOutliers = Pattern.compile("[^\\x00-\\x7F]",
                                    Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.CANON_EQ
                                            | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher unicodeOutlierMatcher = unicodeOutliers.matcher(utf8TweetText );
                utf8TweetText  = unicodeOutlierMatcher.replaceAll(" ");
```

This works great for English.

However, if my text is in urdu like this:

```
تحریک 

انصاف نے زینب کے قتل کے خلاف مذمتی قرارداد سندھ اسمبلی میں جمع کرا دی

 کراچی:مذمتی قرارداد تحریک انصاف کے رکن…
```

Then it replaces all the text in urdu with whitespaces.

How do I remove special characters from a string but make sure it doesn't remove urdu text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All non-word chars can be matched with `\W` shorthand character class, and to make it Unicode-aware, all you need is pass the [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) (or `(?U)` inline embedded flag option) to the regex compiler:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?U)\\W", " ");
```

See the [Java online demo](https://ideone.com/QacXZ2).

If you need to also remove `_` char (it is considered a word char), add `\W` and `_` into a character class:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?U)[\\W_]", " ");
```

To replace 1+ special chars with a single space, add `+` quantifier after the pattern:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?U)[\\W_]+", " ");
```

Comment: Okay i will try this

Comment: It is working for both but it is removing "/ " and " :  " from urls

Comment: Sure, these are special chars. If you want to exclude them globally, use `[\\W_&&[^/:]]`. If you need to avoid matching them in URLs only, the code will become sort of more "complex" because you will have to match URLs, skip handling them and only replace the special chars in other contexts.

Comment: If i want "@" to not be remove i just have to add this to the regex like this right: (?U)\\W_&&[^/:]@] ??

Comment: Add it to the subtracted class - `(?U)[\\W_&&[^/:@]]`. Here, `\\W_` is what we match and `/:@` is a list of chars we want to exclude from matching.